# Is there a way to prevent the horizontally split window from disappearing when I turn off and on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

The edit window in Visual Studio can be split horizontally. But, if I turn Visual Studio off and then back on, **it goes back to normal.**

1. Is there a way to make it stay the same (horizontally split) even if I turn the VS off and on?
2. There is a *"New Horizontal Document Group"* option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378249/10027592), but I couldn't find one in my VS2017 and VS2022. They show "New Vertical Document Group" only. Is this a deprecated feature or can I bring it back through the settings?

Thank you.